# How to add mouse aim to flight script

Tags: unity, c#, mouse, simulations, control

I am making a flight combat game and I want to add mouse aim to control to the flight script I am using. Is there any way I can add mouse aim to my script similar to Warthunder's mouse aim. Mainly since my game is arcady and I want players to not get frustrated with keyboard controls.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Airplane : MonoBehaviour
{
public ControlSurface elevator;
public ControlSurface aileronLeft;
public ControlSurface aileronRight;
public ControlSurface rudder;
public Engine engine;

public WeaponDropper[] weapons;

public Rigidbody Rigidbody { get; internal set; }

private float throttle = 1.0f;
private bool yawDefined = false;

private void Awake()
{
    Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Start()
{
    if (elevator == null)
        Debug.LogWarning(name + ": Airplane missing elevator!");
    if (aileronLeft == null)
        Debug.LogWarning(name + ": Airplane missing left aileron!");
    if (aileronRight == null)
        Debug.LogWarning(name + ": Airplane missing right aileron!");
    if (rudder == null)
        Debug.LogWarning(name + ": Airplane missing rudder!");
    if (engine == null)
        Debug.LogWarning(name + ": Airplane missing engine!");

    try
    {
        Input.GetAxis("Yaw");
        yawDefined = true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(e);
        Debug.LogWarning(name + ": \"Yaw\" axis not defined in Input Manager. Rudder will not work correctly!");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (elevator != null)
    {
        elevator.targetDeflection = -Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }
    if (aileronLeft != null)
    {
        aileronLeft.targetDeflection = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
    if (aileronRight != null)
    {
        aileronRight.targetDeflection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
    if (rudder != null && yawDefined)
    {
        // YOU MUST DEFINE A YAW AXIS FOR THIS TO WORK CORRECTLY.
        // Imported packages do not carry over changes to the Input Manager, so
        // to restore yaw functionality, you will need to add a "Yaw" axis.
        rudder.targetDeflection = Input.GetAxis("Yaw");
    }

    if (engine != null)
    {
        // Fire 1 to speed up, Fire 2 to slow down. Make sure throttle only goes 0-1.
        throttle += Input.GetAxis("Fire1") * Time.deltaTime;
        throttle -= Input.GetAxis("Fire2") * Time.deltaTime;
        throttle = Mathf.Clamp01(throttle);

        engine.throttle = throttle;
    }

    if (weapons.Length > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            foreach (WeaponDropper dropper in weapons)
            {
                dropper.Fire(Rigidbody.GetPointVelocity(dropper.transform.position));
            }
        }
    }
}

private float CalculatePitchG()
{
    // Angular velocity is in radians per second.
    Vector3 localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(Rigidbody.velocity);
    Vector3 localAngularVel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(Rigidbody.angularVelocity);

    // Local pitch velocity (X) is positive when pitching down.

    // Radius of turn = velocity / angular velocity
    float radius = (Mathf.Approximately(localAngularVel.x, 0.0f)) ? float.MaxValue : localVelocity.z / localAngularVel.x;

    // The radius of the turn will be negative when in a pitching down turn.

    // Force is mass * radius * angular velocity^2
    float verticalForce = (Mathf.Approximately(radius, 0.0f)) ? 0.0f : (localVelocity.z * localVelocity.z) / radius;

    // Express in G (Always relative to Earth G)
    float verticalG = verticalForce / -9.81f;

    // Add the planet's gravity in. When the up is facing directly up, then the full
    // force of gravity will be felt in the vertical.
    verticalG += transform.up.y * (Physics.gravity.y / -9.81f);

    return verticalG;
}


private void OnGUI()
{
    const float msToKnots = 1.94384f;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 40, 300, 20), string.Format("Speed: {0:0.0} knots", Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude * msToKnots));
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 60, 300, 20), string.Format("Throttle: {0:0.0}%", throttle * 100.0f));
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 80, 300, 20), string.Format("G Load: {0:0.0} G", CalculatePitchG()));
}
```

}

This is my flight control script for the camera rig. Camera follows the aircraft just fine but I dont know how to link mouse aim to the new flight script my aircraft uses *Show above*

```
/// <summary>
/// Combination of camera rig and controller for aircraft. Requires a properly set
/// up rig. I highly recommend either using or referencing the included prefab.
/// </summary>
public class MouseFlightController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Components")]
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Transform of the aircraft the rig follows and references")]
    private Transform aircraft = null;
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Transform of the object the mouse rotates to generate MouseAim position")]
    private Transform mouseAim = null;
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Transform of the object on the rig which the camera is attached to")]
    private Transform cameraRig = null;
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Transform of the camera itself")]
    private Transform cam = null;

    [Header("Options")]
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Follow aircraft using fixed update loop")]
    private bool useFixed = true;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("How quickly the camera tracks the mouse aim point.")]
    private float camSmoothSpeed = 5f;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Mouse sensitivity for the mouse flight target")]
    private float mouseSensitivity = 3f;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("How far the boresight and mouse flight are from the aircraft")]
    private float aimDistance = 500f;

    [Space]
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("How far the boresight and mouse flight are from the aircraft")]
    private bool showDebugInfo = false;

    private Vector3 frozenDirection = Vector3.forward;
    private bool isMouseAimFrozen = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a point along the aircraft's boresight projected out to aimDistance meters.
    /// Useful for drawing a crosshair to aim fixed forward guns with, or to indicate what
    /// direction the aircraft is pointed.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 BoresightPos
    {
        get
        {
            return aircraft == null
                 ? transform.forward * aimDistance
                 : (aircraft.transform.forward * aimDistance) + aircraft.transform.position;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the position that the mouse is indicating the aircraft should fly, projected
    /// out to aimDistance meters. Also meant to be used to draw a mouse cursor.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 MouseAimPos
    {
        get
        {
            if (mouseAim != null)
            {
                return isMouseAimFrozen
                    ? GetFrozenMouseAimPos()
                    : mouseAim.position + (mouseAim.forward * aimDistance);
            }
            else
            {
                return transform.forward * aimDistance;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (aircraft == null)
            Debug.LogError(name + "MouseFlightController - No aircraft transform assigned!");
        if (mouseAim == null)
            Debug.LogError(name + "MouseFlightController - No mouse aim transform assigned!");
        if (cameraRig == null)
            Debug.LogError(name + "MouseFlightController - No camera rig transform assigned!");
        if (cam == null)
            Debug.LogError(name + "MouseFlightController - No camera transform assigned!");

        // To work correctly, the entire rig must not be parented to anything.
        // When parented to something (such as an aircraft) it will inherit those
        // rotations causing unintended rotations as it gets dragged around.
        transform.parent = null;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (useFixed == false)
            UpdateCameraPos();

        RotateRig();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (useFixed == true)
            UpdateCameraPos();
    }

    private void RotateRig()
    {
        if (mouseAim == null || cam == null || cameraRig == null)
            return;

        // Freeze the mouse aim direction when the free look key is pressed.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            isMouseAimFrozen = true;
            frozenDirection = mouseAim.forward;
        }
        else if  (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C))
        {
            isMouseAimFrozen = false;
            mouseAim.forward = frozenDirection;
        }

        // Mouse input.
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;

        // Rotate the aim target that the plane is meant to fly towards.
        // Use the camera's axes in world space so that mouse motion is intuitive.
        mouseAim.Rotate(cam.right, mouseY, Space.World);
        mouseAim.Rotate(cam.up, mouseX, Space.World);

        // The up vector of the camera normally is aligned to the horizon. However, when
        // looking straight up/down this can feel a bit weird. At those extremes, the camera
        // stops aligning to the horizon and instead aligns to itself.
        Vector3 upVec = (Mathf.Abs(mouseAim.forward.y) > 0.9f) ? cameraRig.up : Vector3.up;

        // Smoothly rotate the camera to face the mouse aim.
        cameraRig.rotation = Damp(cameraRig.rotation,
                                  Quaternion.LookRotation(mouseAim.forward, upVec),
                                  camSmoothSpeed,
                                  Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private Vector3 GetFrozenMouseAimPos()
    {
        if (mouseAim != null)
            return mouseAim.position + (frozenDirection * aimDistance);
        else
            return transform.forward * aimDistance;
    }

    private void UpdateCameraPos()
    {
        if (aircraft != null)
        {
            // Move the whole rig to follow the aircraft.
            transform.position = aircraft.position;
        }
    }

    // Thanks to Rory Driscoll
    // http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2016/03/07/frame-rate-independent-damping-using-lerp/
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates dampened motion between a and b that is framerate independent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">Initial parameter</param>
    /// <param name="b">Target parameter</param>
    /// <param name="lambda">Smoothing factor</param>
    /// <param name="dt">Time since last damp call</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Quaternion Damp(Quaternion a, Quaternion b, float lambda, float dt)
    {
        return Quaternion.Slerp(a, b, 1 - Mathf.Exp(-lambda * dt));
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (showDebugInfo == true)
        {
            Color oldColor = Gizmos.color;

            // Draw the boresight position.
            if (aircraft != null)
            {
                Gizmos.color = Color.white;
                Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(BoresightPos, 10f);
            }

            if (mouseAim != null)
            {
                // Draw the position of the mouse aim position.
                Gizmos.color = Color.red;
                Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(MouseAimPos, 10f);

                // Draw axes for the mouse aim transform.
                Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
                Gizmos.DrawRay(mouseAim.position, mouseAim.forward * 50f);
                Gizmos.color = Color.green;
                Gizmos.DrawRay(mouseAim.position, mouseAim.up * 50f);
                Gizmos.color = Color.red;
                Gizmos.DrawRay(mouseAim.position, mouseAim.right * 50f);
            }

            Gizmos.color = oldColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are photos of the aircraft and how the rig is setup [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see by the bottom image, what I want is the aircraft to move towards the circle so that cross hair lines up with the circle, when it straightens out, the circle should be at the center of the screen again like after a turn.

Comment: There is a lot of code there for moving control surfaces. Do those actually affect the aircraft? For a less simulationist and more gameist flight experience I would usually not bother with simulating control surfaces. I would control the rotation directly and make the control surface flapping purely cosmetic. If that's what you are already doing, then why include that code at all in your question?

Comment: alright, I fixed my problem by using a different script someone from a discord had sent me, only problem is it doesnt simulate gravity and the aircraft wont glide when there is zero thrust and has poor terminal velocity. Its now a bit too arcady it breaks the fun of flying.

Comment: I have been facing some similar issue from days while implementing mouse fly controller. Can you please help and share your latest code ? @Timothy Moore